# Increase cart cost if X is met

Tags: php, oscommerce, fedex

So we have an issue with using a silly item/product based shipping, aka
the user adds a product to the cart (FedEx/USPS) and the cost is added
to shipping. If X amount of items are in teh cart, the rate increases due
to products being shipped via envelope to being shipped via box. This
incurs an additional 20$ service charge. I would like to append an additional
20$ to cart costs if X items are met, but am having an issue with adding this
to the session information (and having it stick). Using this code, I can add
an additional cost to shipping:

```
    # %install_dir%/catalog/checkout_shipping.php
    $_SESSION['cart']->total = $_SESSION['cart']->total + 20;
    var_export($cart);
```

This does not reflect in my shopping cart module/sidebar with he current
price though. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Don't you also want to tell the customer somewhere that they're being charged extra as a line item in their order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a "session_start()" somewhere in this script prior to these lines?

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['cart']->total += 20;
```

Also, you might not want to put it right in the total. I'd put it in a shipping related variable, as well as add it to the running total. That way you can make sure you don't add it again if you've already done it once! Like:

```
session_start();
if (!$_SESSION['cart']->shipping_extra) {
  $_SESSION['cart']->shipping_extra = true;
  $_SESSION['cart']->total += 20;
}
```

Also... # is deprecated, use // or /* !